# Pager on Widget Form Query

Tags: forms, database, paging

The module is a small custom widget for the entity reference field. It creates a list of nodes that allows for multiple selections.

Is it possible to paginate the results of the query even though this is a widget for a field?

```
function outfit_builder_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

///...Additional Code Removed

$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->addTag('node_access');
$query->join('field_data_' . $instance['widget']['settings']['image_field_' . $type], 'fd', 'fd.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->fields('n', array('title', 'nid'));
$query->fields('fd', array($instance['widget']['settings']['image_field_' . $type] . '_fid'));
$query->condition('n.type', $type, '=');
$query->condition('fd.delta', 0, '=');
$query->condition('n.status', 1, '=');
$result = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(21)->execute();
foreach ($result as $node) {
  $options[$node->nid] = theme('image_style', array(
      'style_name'  => $instance['widget']['settings']['image_style'],
      'path'        => file_load($node->{$instance['widget']['settings']['image_field_' . $type] . '_fid'})->uri,
      'title'       => check_plain($node->title),
    )
  );
}

$element += array(
'#type'             => 'checkboxes',
'#options'          => $options,
'#attributes'       => array(
  'class' => array('item'),
),


return $element;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After you extend your query:

```
$result = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(21)->execute();
```

You'll need to also include the pager

```
// Attach the pager theme
$element['pager_pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager',);
```